# Missing lots of images with Http request to retrieve a user's images from Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-get, photos

I have been trying to download all my images from Facebook. I have been using **HTTP** request methods. I have more than about 600 images (people tagged me) on Facebook. With my **HTTP** request I got less than 300. I have **user_photos access token** as to be able to get the photos.
I have tried to set the limit in my request to 600 but this doesn't work.
I've been using in Graph API explorer in my work. 
P.S: All of the images are allowed on timeline.
Thank you.

Comment: There is a limit to what `limit` value you can use – you can not just set it to an arbitrarily high value, and hope to get “all” data with that. You need to use the pagination URLs provided to go through all results.

Comment: Thank you Mr. CBore, But i still have the same problem. I have so many images in the **photos of you** set of images in my profile which are not returned back using an HTTP Get Request. Is there any suggestion about why those images are missed ? Thank you !!

Comment: Mr. @CBroe, the images that are not returned back are those images which i am tagged and are allowed to be shown on the timeline.

Comment: Please add the API call you are making (without the access token, but do include all other request parameters). Please also explain what exactly is failing.